# Why I have different outputs in this C++ code which I could not understand?

Tags: c++, function, oop, c++11

I couldn't understand the output of this program even after a debug, specially the line where you find " f(::x) = h(x) " what does it mean ?
Could someone help me please to understand the C++ program and how it runs to understand the outputs.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int x = 6;
int h(int & x)
{
    x = 2*x; 
    return x;
}
int g(int m)
{
    return x++;
}
int& f(int &x)
{
    x+=::x; 
    return x;
}

int main()
{
   int x = -1;
    f(::x) = h(x);
    cout<<f(x)<<" "<<g(x)<<" "<<h(x)<<" "<<x<<" "<<::x<<endl;
    f(::x) = g(x);
    cout<<f(x)<<" "<<g(x)<<" "<<h(x)<<" "<<x<<" "<<::x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

after compiling the outputs are: 
-5 -2 -4 -2 -2
-11 -2 -10 -5 -2

Comment: We may be able to run/compile this, but attaching the output that you're seeing would be nice.

Comment: Whoever wrote this is a sadist

Comment: @Caleth you can tell that to my teacher

Comment: If that's your assignment, switch scools.

Comment: I get different output: `-5 -2 -4 -2 -2` `-10 -1 -10 -5 -1` in Visual Studio. It looks like your teacher wrote some undefined behavior.

Comment: @Blaze `cout<<f(x)<<" "<<g(x)<<" "<<h(x)<<" "<<x<<" "<<::x<<endl;` is UB, you modify `x` a whole bunch in the arguments to the various `<<`s

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @Caleth. I only looked at the assignment and forgot to check what's going on in the output. What horrible code indeed.

Comment: @Blaze As in my comments to some of the answers: All the modifications happen inside functions, so there is no UB.  The ordering is unspecified, not undefined.

Comment: @MartinBonner Good to know. Thanks for mentioning the proper terminology.

Answer (score 5):

Let's rewrite this so that there isn't any name clashes. Note that many of these functions modify the object they are passed, so while outputting the values are changing. Because the order in which these changes happen is unspecified, the overall result may differ between any two evaluations.

```
#include<iostream>

int global = 6;

int h(int & h_param){ h_param = 2 * h_param; return h_param; }
int g(int ){ return global++; }
int & f(int & f_param){ f_param += global; return f_param; }

int main()
{
    int local = -1;
    f(global) = h(local);
    std::cout << f(local) << " " << g(local) << " " << h(local) << " " << local << " " << global << std::endl;
    f(global) = g(local);
    std::cout << f(local) << " " << g(local) << " " << h(local) << " " << local << " " << global << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you quote chapter and verse for the undefined behaviour claim please?  I believe the fact that it all happens inside functions means that there is none.  (Of course, the sequencing is utterly unpredictable)

Comment: There are sequencing points at function call and function return though.

Answer (score 3):

Thera are two variables with the same name **x**. Global x: "::x" and local "x".

```
f(::x) = h(x);
```

This line transforms to 3 operations:

- h(x) -> -1*2 -> returns -2 and x=-2
- f(::x) -> f(6) -> ::x=12 and returns reference to '::x'
- ::x = -2

```
cout << f(x) << " " << g(x) << " " << h(x) << " " << x << " " << ::x << endl;
```

In this line the evaluation order of calls is unspecified, so the values displayed on the console can vary.
For example, my output is:

```
-5 -2 -4 -5 -1
-10 -1 -10 -10 0
```

You should understand the basic rules:

```
int h(int &x);
```

**int &x** - means that **x** not a copy, it's *reference*. If you change these variable inside function - it changes outside.

```
int g(int m);
```

**int m** - means that **m** is a copy. Changes inside function doesn't affect it outside

```
int & f(int &x);
```

These means that function returns reference to some variable.

Comment: It would be better to say "unpredictable" rather than "undefined".  If the functions were implemented with #define macros rather than proper functions, the code would actually have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Eljay  No, it is *not* undefined behaviour.  In sequence point terms, there is a sequence point at the start and end of each function.  As such there is no UB.  (I'm not familiar enough with "sequenced before"/"sequenced after" to describe it in those terms, but I *am* sure that they didn't make code which had defined behaviour in C++03 UB in C++11.)

Comment: @MartinBonner fixit

Comment: @MartinBonner The distinction is now *unsequenced* vs *indeterminably sequenced*.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the problem is that the code has been written in a terribly obfuscated style.  In particular there is a global variable called `x`, and a local variable in `main` called `x`.  In `f(::x) = h(x)` the `::` means that the argument to `f` is the global, but the argument to `h` is the local.  Let us start by renaming all the variables:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int x = 6;
int h(int &y){y = 2*y; return y;}
int g(int m){return x++;}
int & f(int &z){z+=x; return z;}
int main()
{
    int w = -1;
    f(x) = h(w);
    cout<<f(w)<<" "<<g(w)<<" "<<h(w)<<" "<<w<<" "<<x<<endl;
    f(x) = g(w);
    cout<<f(w)<<" "<<g(w)<<" "<<h(w)<<" "<<w<<" "<<x<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now it becomes a little more obvious that `h` modifies its argument, `g` modifies the global, and `f` modifies it's argument and uses the global.

The output is not defined by the standard, because you don't know what order the functions are called in.

---

```
f(x) = h(w)
```

Means:

- call the function `h`, passing it the value `w` by reference.  On return, `w` will hold -2, and that will be the function result too.
- call the function `f`, passing it the value `x` by reference.  On return `x` will hold 12, and the function will return `x` by reference.  Note that this may happen before or after the call to `h`.
- assign the value returned by `h` (-2) to the reference returned by `f`.

Because this is all happening inside function calls, there is no undefined behaviour, but there are a startling large number of possible outputs.